# how to implement http server push?

Tags: python, web-services

I'm trying to implement a server push service (preferably in Python). Regardless of whether it will be implemented using long polling, websockets, etc, all the examples I've seen have the form

```
def controller(request):
    while True:
        wait()
        when new_data_is_available():
            send_to_client(new_data)
```

The question is: how does the method know when new data is available? Especially in a language like Python, which, as far as I know, does not have a standardized event system??

Comment: That depends on the data - only you can know what 'new data is available' would even mean, and only with that knowledge you may choose the right approach.

Comment: @zwer: let's say a facebook/twitter like service, in which you subscribe to new posts. However, regardless of what "new data" means, my main question is: how can this method be notified that something (anything) happened.

Comment: By using one of the event systems that are available.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: What would that be in python + django/flask for example? If that was a django view, how should that be notified, for example, that an event was sent by a message broker??

Comment: @blue_note - But that's the thing - it depends on how you find out that new data is available - for example, if you have a data stream you can do it right there and then with a simple `read()` on it. Similarly, if the data is completely external to your app you may use some form of IPC, from named pipes to sockets, to inform your data 'sender' that there is new data...

Comment: @zwer: good point. what if the data comes from an event (something sent from a message broker)??

Comment: @blue_note - If it's in the same app it depends how your 'message broker' is operating - if the communicator is in a separate thread, there are several options from `threading.Semaphore` to `threading.Event`. If it's operating as a separate process, check the `multiprocessing.Queue` and `multiprocessing.Manager` structures. If completely external, again, IPC/RPC can be easily achieved through sockets (there are even cute wrappers in the `multiprocessing.connection` package). Your question is way too broad for a simple/decisive answer.